# git svn rebase fails with clean working directory

Tags: git, git-svn

Attempting to do a `git svn rebase` -- it complains I have uncommitted changes though nothing is showing in `git status`.

```
$ git svn rebase
Cannot rebase with uncommited changes:
# On branch local/dev
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git status
# On branch local/dev
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I've cleared the stash, deleted `.git/svn/.caches`, tried `git reset --hard HEAD`, run `git clean -xfd` (though not in that order). Not sure what I'm missing here or what I should try next; as far as I can tell, this is as clean of a working copy as I can have. (And there are no changes that need to be `git svn dcommit`ed.)

Answer (score 0):

Aha. `git reset --hard remotes/$SVN_BRANCH` seems to have made everything happy. I do not know why.